# sed : Replace the string in one variable with another in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace STUDENT (if found in the file FILENAME) with REPLACE.I've been searching for a couple hours now,so it's time for a question. **What is the correct syntax of sed to do it ?**
My best attempt :

```
sed 's/'$STUDENT'/'$REPLACE'/' $FILENAME
```

Comment: Let me know (answer this comment and ping me with `@terdon`) if the duplicate's answers don't solve your issue.

Comment: @terdon, My problem is not solved yet. The problem is that the output is not going to file so something must be wrong with sed. Since you sowed me that post, I changed sed to :  sed "s/$STUDENT/$REPLACE/" $FILENAME  $FILENAME ,and it's working better but when STUDENT is found it is not changed in the file. When I trie to append it using FILENAME >> FILENAME at the and of  sed, it duplicates the whole content of the file. If I use > instead , everything in the output file gets deleted instead of overwriting just the one spot where STUDENT is located.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input and ii) the output you are expecting. `sed` doesn't change the file by default, it just prints the results to the terminal. If you want to change the original file, you need `-i`.